# CIS(Clever Internet Suite) form fieldvalue encode

Tags: delphi, encode, formfield

Delphi XE5 + CIS 7.8 for XE5,when POST use Chinese formfield value like below

clHttpRequest.AddFormField('Status', '待处理');

```
itAutoStatus := '待处理' ;
mmo1.Lines.Add( ' 汉字为 : <'+ itAutoStatus +'>' ) ; // <待处理>
a2us := AnsiToUtf8(itAutoStatus) ;
mmo1.Lines.Add( ' 汉字AnsiToUtf8为 : <' + a2us +'>' ) ; // <待处理>
gbs := HTTPEncode(itAutoStatus);
mmo1.Lines.Add( ' 汉字HTTPEncode为 : <' + gbs +'>' ) ; // <%B4%FD%B4%A6%C0%ED>
utfs := HTTPEncode(AnsiToUtf8(itAutoStatus));
mmo1.Lines.Add( ' 汉字HTTPEncode(AnsiToUtf8())为 : <' + utfs +'>' ) ; // <%E5%BE%85%E5%A4%84%E7%90%86>
```

in IE8,right raw stream is : pageNo=1&total=&SortField=&SortType=&PromTitle=&C1=&Status=**%E5%BE%85%E5%A4%84%E7%90%86**

clHttpRequest.AddFormField('Status', '待处理');

CIS default raw stream is : pageNo=1&total=&SortField=&SortType=&PromTitle=&C1=&Status=**%B4%FD%B4%A6%C0%ED**

clHttpRequest.AddFormField('Status', HTTPEncode(AnsiToUtf8('待处理')));

Now CIS raw stream is : pageNo=1&total=&SortField=&SortType=&PromTitle=&C1=&Status=**%25E5%25BE%2585%25E5%25A4%2584%25E7%2590%2586**

clHttpRequest.AddFormField add string '25',so web server will no database query result.

I want to make raw stream like IE8,How to fix this? thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

solved

clHttpRequest.Header.CharSet := 'UTF-8';

Comment: Perhaps you could set charset to UTF-16 and remove `AnsiToUtf8` alltogether. Anyway, starting with Delphi 2009 i'd not call functions like those reliable...